# How do I post adaptive payment information to paypal?

Tags: post, curl, paypal

I've managed to get an adaptive payments script to work in the apigee console, here is the request:

```
X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: JSON
X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: APP-80W284485P519543T
X-HostCommonName: svcs.sandbox.paypal.com
Host: svcs.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 428
X-PAYPAL-DEVICE-IPADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
X-Forwarded-For: 10.203.10.109
X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-SOURCE: APIGEE-CONSOLE-1.0
X-Target-URI: https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com
X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: JSON
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Connection: Keep-Alive

"{
  "actionType":"PAY",
  "currencyCode":"USD",
  "receiverList":{"receiver":[{"amount":"5.00","email":"cam_1315509411_per@btinternet.com"}]},
  "returnUrl":"http://apigee.com/console/-1/handlePaypalReturn",
  "senderEmail":"qwom_1315508825_biz@btinternet.com",
  "feesPayer":"SENDER",
  "cancelUrl":"http://apigee.com/console/-1/handlePaypalCancel?",
  "requestEnvelope":{"errorLanguage":"en_US", "detailLevel":"ReturnAll"}
}"
```

How do I actually post this information to the https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay url? I can't find the easiest way to do it, should I use cURL and what are the variables names for each post value?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the rest of your application. PHP with cURL is fairly straightforward, but it's not too much of a hassle in other languages either.
PayPal has sample code online at https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/78

If you were to do this yourself, you'd need to (in a nutshell):
- Send a proper HTTP header with the X- headers as shown above including the application ID.
- Send the API call via JSON, SOAP or NVP as POST or GET to the API endpoint
- Decode the response and act accordingly